# UUID_To_BIN equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, binary, guid

I have MySQL 8 database with primary key datatype as Binary(16). I am able to load the record in  using EntityFramework C# and the value of the primary key return is a Guid (34 Characters).

I amd also able to load the required record  in MySQL editor using UUID_TO_BIN('Guid') function and it works perfectly.

My problem is how can I do the same in EntityFramework to load the record?  Is there anything equivalent to UUID_TO_BIN function in C#.

```
Guid guid = new Guid("61306561-6163-3530-2d38-6131322d3131");
member member = context.member.Where(x => x.Id == guid).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Try ToString() :  Where(x => x.Id.ToString()  == guid.ToString())

Comment: @jdweng Thanks I have tried that , unfortunately it did not work as well.

Comment: Compare manually x.Id.ToString() and guid.ToString() to see what you actually are getting.  Also try without the WHERE and change SingleOrDefault() to ToList() to debug and see why you are failing.  I don't want to guess.

Comment: `byte[] guidBytes = guid.ToByteArray()` then compare against that?

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for the suggestion, still did not work : var guid = new Guid("61306561-6163-3530-2d38-6131322d3131");
                byte[] guidBytes = guid.ToByteArray();

                var mem1 = context.member.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id.ToByteArray() == guidBytes).ToList();

Comment: @Charlieface.. Success .. this did the trick ------context.member.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id.ToByteArray().ToString() == guidBytes.ToString())

Comment: If it's a `binary(16)` why does it need `ToByteArray`? The extra `ToString` looks inefficient

Comment: The way EF maps binary(16)  is System.Guid

Comment: @snowflakes74 `context.member.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id.ToByteArray().ToString() == guidBytes.ToString())` -- pretty sure this is comparing `"System.Byte[]" == "System.Byte[]"` which will be trivially true for every value.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger yes you are correct. I have moved away from it for now and just using varchar(64) to hold the guid as the database is quite small and will be small.